# ReactJS infinite scroll built from scratch stops working after a bit

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to learn React by implementing an infinite scroll from scratch.

Algorithm:

1. `arr` is an array of 1000 divs
2. `arr2` is an array slice of 21 divs from `arr`. `arr2` is updated via scrolling.
3. only the elements in `arr2` are supposed to be rendered
4. Console shows the current range of `arr` being rendered

jQuery is included.

It works for a bit. But then stops after around 34 elements. Why?

(Snippet included. Alternatively, here's the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/yonabiv/edit?html,js,console,output )

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
  
  arr.push(i);

}


class Element extends React.Component{

  render() {
      
      const styleObj = {height: 100, backgroundColor:"hotpink"};
    
      return (<div style={styleObj}> {this.props.data} </div>);

  }
}


class List extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      visibleStart: 0,
      visibleEnd: 20
    };
  
  }

  render() {

    var arr2 = arr.slice(this.state.visibleStart, this.state.visibleEnd);
    var renderedOutput = arr2.map((item,index) => <Element data={item} key={index} />)

    return (
      <div>
        {renderedOutput}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this))
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this))
  }

 handleScroll(event) {
    var visibleStart = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop()/100);
    var visibleEnd = visibleStart + 20;
    console.log(visibleStart + " " + visibleEnd);
    this.setState({
        visibleStart: visibleStart,
        visibleEnd: visibleEnd
      });
    
  }
  
}


ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>React Infinite Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have reached to the end of the parent's height, you did that because you only render 20 Elements (each Element is 100px) and that is the parent's height.
You could chain the next set of Elements into the rendered list (store it in the state and just add more elements?).
I did  an example just to illustrate the difference, of course this is not perfect and may have some bugs but this is just to get you understand why it stopped.

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
  
  arr.push(i);

}


class Element extends React.Component{

  render() {
      
      const styleObj = {height: 100, backgroundColor:"hotpink"};
    
      return (<div style={styleObj}> {this.props.data} </div>);

  }
}


class List extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      visibleStart: 0,
      visibleEnd: 20,
      listItems: arr.slice(0, 20)
    };
  
  }

  render() {
    const {listItems} = this.state;
    var renderedOutput = listItems.map((item,index) => <Element data={item} key={index} />)
    return (
      <div>
        {renderedOutput}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this))
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this))
  }

 handleScroll(event) {
    var visibleStart = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop()/100);
    var visibleEnd = visibleStart + 20;
    var nextListItem = [...arr.slice(visibleStart, visibleEnd)];
    console.log(visibleStart + " " + visibleEnd);
    this.setState({
        visibleStart: visibleStart,
        visibleEnd: visibleEnd,
        listItems: [...this.state.listItems, ...nextListItem]
      });
    
  }
  
}


ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>React Infinite Scroll</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app"></div>

</body>

</html>
```